# How to cast void* back to std::vector<float>

Tags: c++, stl, casting

I can construct `data` on Line 19 from `vvp.at(0)` if I know the size of `vf`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef void* VoidPointer;
typedef std::vector< float > VF;
typedef std::vector< VoidPointer > VVP;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VF vf;
    vf.push_back(13.0f);
    vf.push_back(14.0f);
    vf.push_back(15.0f);
    vf.push_back(16.0f);

    VVP vvp;
    vvp.push_back( (VoidPointer)const_cast<float *>( &(vf.front()) ) );

    VF data ( static_cast< float* >( vvp.at(0) ),
              static_cast< float* >( vvp.at(0) ) + vf.size() );

    std::cout << "data.size() is " << data.size() << std::endl;

    for(VF::const_iterator i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "data contains " << *i << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Leaving aside whether this is sensible (the example is contrived) I'd like to know how to cast `vvp.at(0)` to a `std::vector<float>` if I didn't know the size of `vf`.  I'm thinking along the lines of something like:

```
std::vector<float> data( *static_cast< std::vector<float>* >( vvp.at(0) ) );
```

But that causes the program to termintate with std::bad_alloc, I don't mind copying if need be.

Comment: Would just changing `vvp.at(0)` to `&vvp.at(0)` in your last line do the trick?

Comment: I don't understand what the `vvp.push_back((VoidPointer)/*...*/);` call is intended to do. It looks like you try to cast the first element of `vf` to `void*` and append it to `vvp`. Why a `const cast`? And why does the following line assume that there are `vf.size()` elements in `vvp` while only one element has been appended?

Comment: @Matt Phillips: unfortunately not, I get invalid static_cast

Comment: @jogojapan: some of this code is to do with marshalling for an external library api not under my control, that line gets the address of a constant reference to the first element of vf, removes constness and casts to void*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a *cast* from `vvp.at(0)` to a vector, it's a *copy* of an array of floats into a *new* vector.  And you can't copy it without knowing the length.  You only saved a pointer to the first element, so the information was lost.

You could make `std::vector<std::pair<VoidPointer, size_t> > VVP` and save both `&vf.front()` *and* `vf.size()` (or start and end pointers, if you prefer).

You could make `std::vector<VF *>` and store pointers to vectors (i.e. `vvp.push_back(&vf)`) and now there's no casting at all.

Edit:  In case you didn't realize:  The pointer `&vf` is unrelated to `&vf.front()`.  `vf` is a structure which contains the pointer `&vf.front()` (or a way to get it).  There's no information in just the address `&vf.front()` to let you find `&vf`.

Comment: You could also use a vector of boost::any and add all kinds of types in there, if that's what you're after.

Comment: @Ben Jackson - thanks for your reply "That is not a cast from vvp.at(0) to a vector", yes that's why I used the word construct for line 19 and said I don't mind copying for the bad_alloc code, I'm mostly interested in knowing for sure if a cast is possible at all

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is extremely non-portable (and equally crazy). Each vector allocates a contiguous array of memory. Any allocation function has to keep track of how many bytes have been allocated, so that it can de-allocate them given only the beginning of the allocation's address.

AFAIK, the C++ standard does not specify how this book keeping is done and therefore, this up to each compiler. One method is to write a count before the actual allocation address - I believe this is what the Visual C++ compiler does. (Eg. if allocating at 0x104, a 32-bit count could be stored at 0x100). Again, you will have to know how your specific compiler does this book keeping.

Anyway, the point is, once you do, a little pointer arithmetic and de-referencing could theoretically look up the allocated size (I'm of course assuming you're still using a vector with a default allocator here), and figure out how many floats were actually allocated using only a void pointer.

Here's an example that works in Visual Studio in 32-bit debug mode:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

size_t bytes_allocated( void* p )
{
#ifndef _DEBUG
#error Doesn't work
#endif // _DEBUG
    size_t const offset = 12;
    size_t const counter_size = 4;
    size_t const total_offset = offset + counter_size;
    void* counter_address = ((char*)p)-total_offset;
    size_t* count = reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(counter_address);
    return *count;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    typedef float test_type;
    std::vector<test_type> v;
    v.push_back(23);
    v.push_back(23);
    v.push_back(23);
    size_t count = bytes_allocated(&v[0]);
    std::cout<<count<<" bytes allocated\n";
    std::cout<<count/sizeof(test_type)<<" items allocated\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
12 bytes allocated
3 items allocated
```

Comment: Wildly nonportable even if you can get it to work (and I know of allocators where this trick is impossible) **plus** the allocated size is equal to *or greater than* the required size, so you still don't know how many floats are really there.

Comment: Agreed. Its absolutely horrible and I've said as much myself in my answer. Even my sample code says it does not work in Release mode. A down vote is a bit harsh for that, don't you think? The question did say "Leaving aside whether this is sensible". That is the only reason I ever suggested this. I hope you did not get the idea I was actually suggesting its use :)